# Confluence loads JIRA issues indefinitely

Tags: jira, confluence

I'm having trouble with Confluence page which uses JIRA issues macro. Certain issues in my project have loading animation next to them with text "Getting issue details ...". Indefinitely. Do you have any suggestion where should I look for hints what might be wrong? I checked JIRA access log and catalina.out but I don't see any errors. I suspect that this behaviour is caused by wrong permissions or something like that? Or perhaps something specific on issue level, fields, assignees, component ...? Thanks.

Matthew

Comment: would be good to add some screenshot or give a bit more details ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We suffer analogous trouble but from the other side: a rolling hourglass in jira for some confluence reference. There is an error message in the log on an html error.

The problem is not permanent probably depending on the current load.

A temporary relieve is to restart both. According to research on Atlassian website the way should be to upgrade to jira 7.3.